# Highcharter and Shiny with reactive dataset/mutated dataset within server function not working

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, reactive, r-highcharter

When I try to produce a highcharter barplot within Shiny using a dataset that is grouped and summarized based on the selectInput values and these same values are referenced within hcaes() I get the error "object 'input' not found"

I have also tried hcaes_string() and then I get "object 'My.Variable' not found" but when I just put in My.Variable, it will produce the hchart so it can interact with the dataset being created within the server function. Obviously I'd like to switch between My.Variable and My.Variable2 with the dropdown. I've tried assigning the summarized dataset to a reactive object, but then I get the error "Objects of class/type reactiveExpr/reactive/function are not supported by hchart (yet)."

I've been at this for hours and this is my first question on StackOverflow. I rigged up a sample dataset so that the code is reproducible and I've updated R and RStudio to the latest versions.

```
library('highcharter')
library('plyr')
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
library('lubridate')
library('stringr')
library('tools')
library('shiny')

#demo <- read.csv("data/name-change-analysis.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

indiv <- rep(c('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'),4)
Name.Change <- rep(c('yes','yes','no','yes','no'),4)
Overall.Category <- rep(c('against','support','support','neutral','against'),4)
Race <- rep(c('Black','White','White','Asian','White'),4)
Gender <- rep(c('Male','Male','Male','Female','Male'),4)

demo <- as.data.frame(cbind(indiv,Name.Change,Overall.Category,Race,Gender))

ui <- 
  navbarPage(
    "Responses by demographics",
    tabPanel(
      "Manual labels",
      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(
            selectInput(
              "category",
              label = "Select a demographic category:",
              choices = c("Race",
                          "Gender" = "gender")
            ),
            width = 6
          ),
          column(
            selectInput(
              "name_or_overall",
              label = "Response Category",
              choices = c(
                "Name Change" = "Name.Change",
                "Overall Category" = "Overall.Category"
              ),
              width = "100%"
            ),
            width = 6
          )
        ),
        highchartOutput("hcontainer")
      )
    ),
    collapsible = TRUE
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
  
  demo %>%
    group_by(input$category,input$name_or_overall) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    hchart(type = "bar",
           hcaes(y = "count",
                 x = as.name(input$category),
                 group = as.name(input$name_or_overall))) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = "percent")) %>%
    hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
  
})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Hi Rprospector. Whats the error message you're receiving from `hcaes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    df1 <- demo %>% mutate(var1=demo[[as.name(input$category)]], var2=demo[[as.name(input$name_or_overall)]])
    df <- df1 %>% group_by(var1,var2) %>% summarise(count = n())
    highchart() %>% 
      hc_add_series(df, type = "bar",
                    hcaes(y = "count",
                          x = "var1",
                          group = "var2")) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = "percent")) %>%
      hc_tooltip(shared = FALSE)
  })
```

You will get the following output:

[image: output]